# spring Kafka integration testing with embedded Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have spring boot application that had a consumer consumes from topic in one cluster and produces to another topic in different cluster.

Now I'm trying to write integration test case using spring embedded Kafka but having an issue `KafkaTemplate could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource`

**Consumer Class**

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumerService {

@Autowired
private KafkaProducerService kafkaProducerService;

@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.producer.topic}")
public void professor(List<Professor> pro) {
    pro.forEach(kafkaProducerService::produce);
    
   }

}
```

**Producer Class**

```
@Service
public class KafkaProducerService {

@Value("${kafka.producer.topic}")
private String topic;

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

public void produce(Professor pro) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(topic,"professor",pro);
  }

 }
```

In my Test cases I want to override `KafkaTemplate` so that when i call `kafkaConsumerService.professor` method in `Test` it should produce the data into embedded Kafka and i should validate it.

**Test config**

```
@TestConfiguration
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, controlledShutdown = false,
brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:3333", "port=3333"})
public class KafkaProducerConfigTest {

@Autowired
 KafkaEmbedded kafkaEmbeded;

@Autowired
KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {
    ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(messageListenerContainer, 
    kafkaEmbeded.getPartitionsPerTopic());
  }
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(kafkaEmbeded));
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
    KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    return kafkaTemplate;
   }

 }
```

**Test class**

```
@EnableKafka
@SpringBootTest(classes = {KafkaProducerConfigTest.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class KafkaProducerServiceTest {

@Autowired
private KafkaConsumerService kafkaConsumerService;

@Test
public void testReceive() throws Exception {
     kafkaConsumerService.professor(Arrays.asList(new Professor()));
     
     //How to check messages is sent to kafka?
}

 }
```

**Error**

```
 The bean 'kafkaTemplate', defined in com.kafka.configuration.KafkaProducerConfigTest, could not be registered. 
 A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/kafka/configuration/KafkaProducerConfig.class] and overriding is disabled.
 Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

---

And also can some one help me how to validate messages sent into embedded Kafka server?

**Note** I'm having some deprecated warnings

> The type KafkaEmbedded is deprecated
>
> The method getPartitionsPerTopic() from the type KafkaEmbedded is deprecated
>
> The method producerProps(KafkaEmbedded) from the type KafkaTestUtils is deprecated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot 2.1 [disables bean overriding by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding).

> Bean overriding has been disabled by default to prevent a bean being accidentally overridden. If you are relying on overriding, you will need to set `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` to `true`.

Regarding the deprecations; see the javadocs for `@EmbeddedKafka`. It is replaced by `EmbeddedKafkaBroker`.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir, I did that but now different issue  `Field kafkaEmbeded in com.kafka.configuration.KafkaProducerConfigTest required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.KafkaEmbedded' that could not be found.`

Comment: As I said; it's `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` now. `@Autowired
 public EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker;`.